# Excel 'procedure is too large' ,how to make code smaller

Tags: excel, vba

Tried all sort of things, just wont work, need the code to be smaller so i can expand macro.
Thanx

```
Dim m2 As Variant
Dim n2 As Variant
Dim m3 As Variant
Dim n3 As Variant
Dim m4 As Variant
Dim n4 As Variant
' and so on ...
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Badentry
If Range("m2").Value = 1 And m2 <> 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:l2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = " send thru macro "
  .Item.To = "d@gmail.com"
  .Item.Subject = "ALERT"
  .Item.Send
 End With

End If
m2 = Range("m2").Value

If Range("n2").Value = 1 And n2 <> 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:l2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = " send thru macro "
  .Item.To = "@gmail.com"
  .Item.Subject = "ALERT"
  .Item.Send
End With
End If
n2 = Range("n2").Value
Badentry:
' and so on...
End sub
```

Comment: Share your code and error message.

Comment: The code go for 110 rows and i need it to go for 1000.

Comment: What is the point of this code `m2 = Range("m2").Value` - do you need to store values for some reason?

Comment: When the value of the cell N2,3,4,5...Or M2,3,4,5..... change to No1 , to select range from the same row as the row in wich the change ocurred  eg.A2:l2 and to send the selection to email

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help a lot:

```
  Sub1 Range("n2"), n2
  Sub1 Range("m2"), m2
  ' and so on ..

Sub Sub1(zRange As Range, zValue As Variant)
  If zRange.Value = 1 And zValue <> 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:l2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = " send thru macro "
      .Item.To = "@gmail.com"
      .Item.Subject = "ALERT"
      .Item.Send
    End With
  End If
  zValue = zRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: @omegastripes - Thank you so much -- I had just noticed my misfeasance. I was going to make it `n2 = Func1(Range("n2"), n2)`. Yours is great.

Comment: Passing arguments ByRef sometimes has an advantages, and also sometimes gets to permanently stuck, isn't it? :)